# Converting text to date works on one system but not on others

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro Excel file for sorting some data and to do some `Vlookup` function with the same data.
The macro is working perfectly in my system. The same macro I shared with my colleague he is also using the same dataset but the final result are not correct, or not matching with my results.

How we can fix this please?

The dataset is quite large. Nearly 200k lines are there.

They are not getting any errors. The macro is running the full code without any errors in their system as well, but the final report is not matching or not correct.

The mismatch is coming only for the date area. There is column with dates `mm/dd/yyyy` formated as text.
I used to convert this text formated date into date then I have to remove all the future dates from the column.

This function alone not working properly for others. Rest all the part is clear. But this is working perfectly in my system.

Below are the Code i used to covert the text date into numeric date and removing the future date then change the available date into old format

```
    Private Sub TermDateRemove()

Dim CellValue, OldFrmtDate As String
Dim y, Tday As Date
Dim EmpTerDate As Range
Dim EmpTerDatePos As Integer
Sheets("Emp Data").Activate
LR = Worksheets("Emp Data").UsedRange.Rows.count
LC = Worksheets("Emp Data").UsedRange.Columns.count

If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End If

Set EmpTerDate = Sheets("Emp Data").Range("1:1").Find("Employee Termination Date", , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False, , False)
    EmpTerDatePos = EmpTerDate.Column
    
txt2clm (EmpTerDatePos) 'Calling text to column function

Tday = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yy")
With Worksheets("Emp Data")
    .Range("1:1").AutoFilter Field:=EmpTerDatePos, Criteria1:=">" & Tday, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).count > 1 Then
With Worksheets("Emp Data")
    .Range(.Cells(2, EmpTerDatePos), .Cells(LR, EmpTerDatePos)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Value = ""
End With
End If
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End If

Columns(EmpTerDatePos).NumberFormat = "@"

For Each cell In Sheets("EMP DATA").UsedRange.Columns(EmpTerDatePos).Cells
    CellValue = cell.Value
    If CellValue = "Employee Termination Date" Then
     'do nothing
    ElseIf CellValue <> "" And CellValue <> "Employee Termination Date" Then
        CVtoDate = Format(CellValue, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        OldFrmtDate = Replace(CVtoDate, "-", "/")
        cell.Value = OldFrmtDate
    End If
Next

Workbooks("Employee Data").Save
End Sub
```

-----Function-----

```
    Function txt2clm(cc As Long) As Long

'Text to column for changing the date into numeric format
    Columns(cc).Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, cc), ActiveSheet.Cells(1, cc)), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 3), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Function
```

Comment: *"with date mm/dd/yyyy format as text"* This is your issue. Dates that are not numeric but are actually just text are the worst case scenario. Dates must be saved as numeric dates, the only useful case where a date should be converted to text is for displaying/printing purpose **only**. • Please [edit] your question and show the function/procedure that converts those texts into real dates as there lies the issue. The conversion is probably not done correctly. [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/).

Comment: Is your colleague in a different country? Sounds like they have a different Excel date format.

Comment: @DS_London Doesn't need to be in a different country. It's enough that you don't like your countrie's standard date format and you prefer something more solid like the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format (like I do). If you know what I mean: https://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: @Pᴇʜ True. Just that whenever I have come across similar issues it is from sheets/programs going to & fro across the Atlantic.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments
@Pᴇʜ The dataset are actually receiving from another team with the same format, so we can't expect the dates will be saved in the numeric format.

Comment: @Rishwan Well then you need to show us your code. I assume something in the conversion went wrong.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Code i updated the code now . i am just a beginner in the coding world. so please bear with me ;)

Comment: Hi DS_London . they are not from different country. same location only

Comment: @Rishwan I don't get why you use `TextToColumns`? That function definitely does not convert text into proper dates. Maybe Excel does some random guessing about the text. But this will definitely not work reliable. • And then you use a text `Tday = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yy")` to filter your data. Note that `Format` returns a String but not a date.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Actually with 'Texttocolumns' function the texted dates are changing into numeric format. i manually cross checked with the some random samples. the dates are correct

Comment: @Rishwan No that will randomly work on your computer and randomly not work on others. This is letting excel guess and far from reliable. Give me a second to show you a reliable way to do that.

Comment: You need to loop through the entire column and process each value. Use `Split()` to split `dd/mm/yy` into day, month and year. Then use `DateSerial(year, month, day)` to get a numeric date. Write that back to the cell. This is the *only* reliable way to convert text to date. Anything else is letting Excel "guess" and might have another outcome on another computer.

Comment: Sure @Pᴇʜ . Thank you for your effort and time :)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Can you please edit in the code itself ?. So i can try .. i am not aware about the split() command and all

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I tried to save the split value into one variable with the below code. but it showing "Run time error 13" Type mismatch

`CellValue = "31/12/2021"
DayFromDate = Split(CellValue, "/")`

Comment: Thank you @Pᴇʜ figured out :)

Comment: i added this for converting date

`For Each cell In Sheets("Emp Data").UsedRange.Columns(EmpTerDatePos).Cells
        CellValue = cell.Value
    If CellValue = "Employee Termination Date" Then
     'do nothing
    ElseIf CellValue <> "" And CellValue <> "Employee Termination Date" Then
        SplitDate = Split(CellValue, "/")
        DayFromDate = SplitDate(1)
        MonthFromDate = SplitDate(0)
        YearFromDate = SplitDate(2)
        NumDate = DateSerial(CInt(YearFromDate), CInt(MonthFromDate), CInt(DayFromDate))
        cell.Value = NumDate
    End If
Next`

Comment: @Rishwan If this solved your issue you can post it as an answer instead of a comment. So it might be useful for future readers. And you can mark your question as solved if you got an answer.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i think i don't have enough reputation to answer a question, or i couldn't find where or how to answer for a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the `String` (looking like a date) `dd/mm/yy` into a real/numeric date by splitting it into parts by `/` and using `DateSerial`.

```
Dim Cell As Range
For Each cell In Sheets("Emp Data").UsedRange.Columns(EmpTerDatePos).Cells
    Dim CellValue As String
    CellValue = cell.Value

    If CellValue <> vbNullString And CellValue <> "Employee Termination Date" Then  
        Dim SplitDate As String
        SplitDate = Split(CellValue, "/")         

        Dim DayFromDate As Integer
        DayFromDate = CInt(SplitDate(1))

        Dim MonthFromDate As Integer
        MonthFromDate = CInt(SplitDate(0))  

        Dim YearFromDate As Integer
        YearFromDate = CInt(SplitDate(2))  
   
        Dim NumDate As Date
        NumDate = DateSerial(YearFromDate, MonthFromDate, DayFromDate)         
        cell.Value = NumDate     
    End If 
Next
```

Also make sure you don't use a `String` as filter criteria, this might fail on other computers again. Never use `Strings` for date.

Even you `Dim Tday As Date` the `Format` function returns a `String` that you then implicitly cast into a numeric `Date` variable if you do `Tday = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yy")`. That means Excel has to guess if the `String` that comes out of the `Format` function is `dd/mm/yy` or `mm/dd/yy`. Even you specified that, VBA is not smart enough to use that information for interpretation of that string.

So what you do instead is:

```
Dim Tday As Date
Tday = Date

With Worksheets("Emp Data")
    .Range("1:1").AutoFilter Field:=EmpTerDatePos, Criteria1:=">" & CDbl(Tday), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With
```

Here we convert the date `Tday` into a `Double` using `CDbl(Tday)`. All numeric dates/times are represented by a number of the type `Double`. Therefore we use a `Double` as criteria. This is much more reliable as your code and will work on any county localization.

Last but not least try to avoid `ActiveSheet` and an explicit reference like `Worksheets("Emp Data")` so the code even works when your sheet is not active.